# need explanation about bookmarking

Tags: html

I got stumbled upon this issue once and I guess I need some expertise in getting through this .." some links that one likes to bookmark ." I tried browsing and got confused. is bookmarking just means the use of CTRL + D. Or is ti something like the one in this [link](http://www.addthis.com/) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bookmarking" comes from **marking** a page in a **book** with a **bookmark**, i.e. a piece of paper or something you put between pages to remember that page. In the same way you can mark web *pages* to return to them later. This usually just means saving the URL of the page in the browser.

So called *social* bookmarking is a technique where the URL is not saved in the user's local browser, but on a service such as del.icio.us, so others can see what you have bookmarked.

The basic idea is to **remember a page you were on** for later reference, that's all it means.

Comment: Thanks deceze .. so please tell me is there a way to get the social bookmarking feature from anywhere???

Comment: i might sound stupid.. but can I change the button there... will that be any copyright issues .. if I change the image the way I want that to appear on my site???

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarking is storing the links somewhere. It can be a bookmark on your browser or even online something like StumbleUpen or Read It Later or even social bookmarking like sharethis.com

Answer (score 0):

It can mean both, bookmarking generally means to add it to your favorites. Although, times they are a changing!

Answer (score 0):

It is same as with "plain old bookmarks": You somehow keep a reference to a certain page. But instead using some physical indicator (what is obviously not possible with the computer ;)) you store the URL somewhere for fast access (in a way it is writing down the page number of a book).